# arangoimport: edge attribute missing or invalid

Tags: arangodb, arangoimport

- **ArangoDB Version**:        3.8
- **Storage Engine**:
- **Deployment Mode**:       Single Server
- **Deployment Strategy**:   Manual Start
- **Operating System**:        Ubuntu 20.04
- **Total RAM in your machine**:  32Gb
- **Disks in use**:        < SSD
- **Used Package**:              < Ubuntu .deb

**Affected feature**: arangoimport

```
(base) raphy@pc:~$ arangodb
2021-11-04T09:34:45+01:00 |INFO| Starting arangodb version 0.15.3, build 814f8be component=arangodb
2021-11-04T09:34:45+01:00 |INFO| Using storage engine 'rocksdb' component=arangodb
2021-11-04T09:34:45+01:00 |INFO| Serving as master with ID 'ef664d42' on :8528... component=arangodb
2021-11-04T09:34:45+01:00 |INFO| Waiting for 3 servers to show up.
 component=arangodb
2021-11-04T09:34:45+01:00 |INFO| Use the following commands to start other servers: component=arangodb

arangodb --starter.data-dir=./db2 --starter.join 127.0.0.1

arangodb --starter.data-dir=./db3 --starter.join 127.0.0.1

2021-11-04T09:34:45+01:00 |INFO| ArangoDB Starter listening on 0.0.0.0:8528 (:8528) component=arangodb
```

I'm trying to `import` data in this way:

```
(base) raphy@pc:~$ arangoimport --server.database "ConceptNet" --collection "rel_type" "./ConceptNet/conceptnet.jsonl"
```

But I get these errors:

```
Connected to ArangoDB 'http+tcp://127.0.0.1:8529, version: 3.8.2, database: 'ConceptNet', username: 'root'
----------------------------------------
database:               ConceptNet
collection:             rel_type
create:                 no
create database:        no
source filename:        ./ConceptNet/conceptnet.jsonl
file type:              json
threads:                2
on duplicate:           error
connect timeout:        5
request timeout:        1200
----------------------------------------
Starting JSON import...
2021-11-04T14:49:48Z [165643] INFO [9ddf3] {general} processed 1945 bytes (3%) of input file
2021-11-04T14:49:48Z [165643] WARNING [e5a29] {general} at position 0: creating document failed with error 'edge attribute missing or invalid', offending document: {"_from":"pm","_to":"am","rel":{"rel_type":"Antonym","language":"en","license":"-sa/4.0","sources":"/s/resource/wiktionary/fr","process":"/s/process/wikiparsec/2"}}
2021-11-04T14:49:48Z [165643] WARNING [e5a29] {general} at position 1: creating document failed with error 'edge attribute missing or invalid', offending document: {"_from":"red","_to":"amber","rel":{"rel_type":"Antonym","language":"en","license":"-sa/4.0","sources":"/s/resource/wiktionary/en","process":"/s/process/wikiparsec/2"}}
2021-11-04T14:49:48Z [165643] WARNING [e5a29] {general} at position 2: creating document failed with error 'edge attribute missing or invalid', offending document: {"_from":"proprium","_to":"apelativum","rel":{"rel_type":"Antonym","language":"en","license":"-sa/4.0","sources":"/s/resource/wiktionary/en","process":"/s/process/wikiparsec/2"}}
2021-11-04T14:49:48Z [165643] WARNING [e5a29] {general} at position 3: creating document failed with error 'edge attribute missing or invalid', offending document: {"_from":"s","_to":"beze\t","rel":{"rel_type":"Antonym","language":"en","license":"-sa/4.0","sources":"/s/resource/wiktionary/en","process":"/s/process/wikiparsec/2"}}
2021-11-04T14:49:48Z [165643] WARNING [e5a29] {general} at position 4: creating document failed with error 'edge attribute missing or invalid', offending document: {"_from":"euphoria","_to":"bad_trip","rel":{"rel_type":"Antonym","language":"en","license":"-sa/4.0","sources":"/s/resource/wiktionary/en","process":"/s/process/wikiparsec/2"}}
2021-11-04T14:49:48Z [165643] WARNING [e5a29] {general} at position 5: creating document failed with error 'edge attribute missing or invalid', offending document: {"_from":"gooder","_to":"badder","rel":{"rel_type":"Antonym","language":"en","license":"-sa/4.0","sources":"/s/resource/wiktionary/en","process":"/s/process/wikiparsec/2"}}
2021-11-04T14:49:48Z [165643] WARNING [e5a29] {general} at position 6: creating document failed with error 'edge attribute missing or invalid', offending document: {"_from":"goodest","_to":"baddest","rel":{"rel_type":"Antonym","language":"en","license":"-sa/4.0","sources":"/s/resource/wiktionary/en","process":"/s/process/wikiparsec/2"}}
2021-11-04T14:49:48Z [165643] WARNING [e5a29] {general} at position 7: creating document failed with error 'edge attribute missing or invalid', offending document: {"_from":"goodie","_to":"baddie","rel":{"rel_type":"Antonym","language":"en","license":"-sa/4.0","sources":"/s/resource/wiktionary/en","process":"/s/process/wikiparsec/2","contributor":"/s/resource/wiktionary/fr"}}
2021-11-04T14:49:48Z [165643] WARNING [e5a29] {general} at position 8: creating document failed with error 'edge attribute missing or invalid', offending document: {"_from":"windy","_to":"calm","rel":{"rel_type":"Antonym","language":"en","license":"-sa/4.0","sources":"/s/resource/wiktionary/en","process":"/s/process/wikiparsec/2"}}
2021-11-04T14:49:48Z [165643] WARNING [e5a29] {general} at position 9: creating document failed with error 'edge attribute missing or invalid', offending document: {"_from":"anger","_to":"calm_down","rel":{"rel_type":"Antonym","language":"en","license":"-sa/4.0","sources":"/s/resource/wiktionary/fr","process":"/s/process/wikiparsec/2"}}
2021-11-04T14:49:48Z [165643] WARNING [e5a29] {general} at position 10: creating document failed with error 'edge attribute missing or invalid', offending document: {"_from":"get_angry","_to":"calm_down","rel":{"rel_type":"Antonym","language":"en","license":"-sa/4.0","sources":"/s/resource/wiktionary/fr","process":"/s/process/wikiparsec/2"}}

created:          0
warnings/errors:  11
updated/replaced: 0
ignored:          0
```

This is the `jsonl` file I'm trying to import :

`conceptnet.jsonl` :

```
{"_from":"pm","_to":"am","rel":{"rel_type":"Antonym","language":"en","license":"-sa/4.0","sources":"/s/resource/wiktionary/fr","process":"/s/process/wikiparsec/2"}}
{"_from":"red","_to":"amber","rel":{"rel_type":"Antonym","language":"en","license":"-sa/4.0","sources":"/s/resource/wiktionary/en","process":"/s/process/wikiparsec/2"}}
{"_from":"proprium","_to":"apelativum","rel":{"rel_type":"Antonym","language":"en","license":"-sa/4.0","sources":"/s/resource/wiktionary/en","process":"/s/process/wikiparsec/2"}}
{"_from":"s","_to":"beze\t","rel":{"rel_type":"Antonym","language":"en","license":"-sa/4.0","sources":"/s/resource/wiktionary/en","process":"/s/process/wikiparsec/2"}}
{"_from":"euphoria","_to":"bad_trip","rel":{"rel_type":"Antonym","language":"en","license":"-sa/4.0","sources":"/s/resource/wiktionary/en","process":"/s/process/wikiparsec/2"}}
{"_from":"gooder","_to":"badder","rel":{"rel_type":"Antonym","language":"en","license":"-sa/4.0","sources":"/s/resource/wiktionary/en","process":"/s/process/wikiparsec/2"}}
{"_from":"goodest","_to":"baddest","rel":{"rel_type":"Antonym","language":"en","license":"-sa/4.0","sources":"/s/resource/wiktionary/en","process":"/s/process/wikiparsec/2"}}
{"_from":"goodie","_to":"baddie","rel":{"rel_type":"Antonym","language":"en","license":"-sa/4.0","sources":"/s/resource/wiktionary/en","process":"/s/process/wikiparsec/2","contributor":"/s/resource>
{"_from":"windy","_to":"calm","rel":{"rel_type":"Antonym","language":"en","license":"-sa/4.0","sources":"/s/resource/wiktionary/en","process":"/s/process/wikiparsec/2"}}
{"_from":"anger","_to":"calm_down","rel":{"rel_type":"Antonym","language":"en","license":"-sa/4.0","sources":"/s/resource/wiktionary/fr","process":"/s/process/wikiparsec/2"}}
{"_from":"get_angry","_to":"calm_down","rel":{"rel_type":"Antonym","language":"en","license":"-sa/4.0","sources":"/s/resource/wiktionary/fr","process":"/s/process/wikiparsec/2"}}
```

[image]

[image]

I tried to modify the line in the `jsonl` file as follows:

```
{"_from":"pm","_to":"am","rel_type":"Antonym","language":"en","license":"-sa/4.0","sources":"/s/resource/wiktionary/fr","process":"/s/process/wikiparsec/2"}
```

But still get this error:

```
(base) raphy@pc:~$ arangoimport --server.database "ConceptNet" --collection "rel_type" "./ConceptNet/conceptnet.jsonl"
Please specify a password: 
Connected to ArangoDB 'http+tcp://127.0.0.1:8529, version: 3.8.2, database: 'ConceptNet', username: 'root'
----------------------------------------
database:               ConceptNet
collection:             rel_type
create:                 no
create database:        no
source filename:        ./ConceptNet/conceptnet.jsonl
file type:              json
threads:                2
on duplicate:           error
connect timeout:        5
request timeout:        1200
----------------------------------------
Starting JSON import...
2021-11-04T18:48:55Z [37684] WARNING [e5a29] {general} at position 0: creating document failed with error 'edge attribute missing or invalid', offending document: {"_from":"pm","_to":"am","rel_type":"Antonym","language":"en","license":"-sa/4.0","sources":"/s/resource/wiktionary/fr","process":"/s/process/wikiparsec/2"}
```

What am I doing wrongly or missing? How to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I found that saving the documents into the `jsonl` file as following, solves the problem:

`conceptnet.jsonl` :

```
{"_from":"conceptnet/pm","_to":"conceptnet/am","rel":{"rel_type":"Antonym","language":"en","license":"-sa/4.0","sources":"/s/resource/wiktionary/fr","process":"/s/process/wikiparsec/2"}}
{"_from":"conceptnet/red","_to":"conceptnet/amber","rel":{"rel_type":"Antonym","language":"en","license":"-sa/4.0","sources":"/s/resource/wiktionary/en","process":"/s/process/wikiparsec/2"}}
{"_from":"conceptnet/proprium","_to":"conceptnet/apelativum","rel":{"rel_type":"Antonym","language":"en","license":"-sa/4.0","sources":"/s/resource/wiktionary/en","process":"/s/process/wikiparsec/2"}}
```

[image]